# Unable to establish network connection between two servers

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tcp

I have 7 Ubuntu 14.04.4 servers running in EC2.  One server is hosting memcached (port 11211) and the other 6 are clients.  **Of the 6 clients, 5 are able to connect and one is not (see note).**

I've taken a TCP dump of both sides of the connection.  I saw that the client sent a SYN request, but no ACK was sent back.  The tcpdump looked like this for the failed connection (the SYNs repeat many times after this)

```
1   0.000000    172.16.1.58 172.16.1.94 TCP 76  43469 → 11211 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=849737 TSecr=0 WS=128
```

And for a successful connection from a different server:

```
1   0.000000    172.16.1.64 172.16.1.94 TCP 76  44908 → 11211 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=19201098 TSecr=0 WS=128
2   0.000298    172.16.1.64 172.16.1.94 TCP 68  44908 → 11211 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=19201098 TSecr=3160738522
```

Some more traces & commands:

```
working-client$ nc -vnz 172.16.1.94 11211
Connection to 172.16.1.94 11211 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

broken-client$ nc -vnz 172.16.1.94 11211
nc: connect to 172.16.1.94 port 11211 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out

broken-client$ nc -vnz -q 5 -u 172.16.1.94 11211 
Connection to 172.16.1.94 11211 port [udp/*] succeeded!
```

Routing table (identical on all clients & server)

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ip-172-16-1-1.e 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.1.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

IP Tables on the broken client

```
broken-client$ sudo iptables -nvL -t nat
--------------------------------------

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination    

broken-client$ sudo iptables -nvL
--------------------------------------

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

IP Tables on the server

```
server$ sudo iptables -nvL -t nat
--------------------------------------

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 7332 packets, 531K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 7332 packets, 531K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 370 packets, 25781 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 370 packets, 25781 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        

server$ sudo iptables -nvL
--------------------------------------
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1963K packets, 341M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination   

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2670K packets, 5518M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

All the clients were cloned from the same base image and should be identical.  We aren't using iptables, all the servers are on the same subnet and security group.

The problem isn't with memcached: I can reproduce the problem with telnet (port 22 or port 11211) or ssh, neither are allowed to connect, though they are allowed by the security group.

Ping is disabled, but I can traceroute between servers (cache <=> client, client <=> cache) as long as its not these two servers.

It appears (see traces above) that a UDP connection can be established, but not TCP.

The problem is persistent.

*Note: the 6 client servers are part of an auto-scaling group (in a VPC).  There are between 1 and 6 servers, depending on load, and sometimes one server fails to connect.  IP addresses and server names do get reused.*

**What can I look at to find where the connection is failing?**

Comment: If they're all simple clones, why don't you just remove the faulty one and recreate it, or as I mentioned previously, try a different IP address to clarify if the IP is linked to the issue?

Comment: Are you sure the security groups are all the same for each client?  Are they on the same subnet?  If they're on different subnets, are you sure the network ACLs for each subnet allow connections to the memcached server?

Comment: I can't change the IP address of the server since its on a VPC - the IP address is fixed unless I terminate the server.  Removing the faulty server and re-adding works, but this is the 5th or so time this has happened, I'd like to get to the root cause.  

The security groups and subnets are all the same and the ACL allows connection to ports 22 and 11211 on the memcached server.  Each of the clients can connect to each other, and all but this one faulty server can connect to the cache server.  The faulty server has no problems connecting to other clients and our database server.

Comment: Is it always happening on the same IP?

Comment: Difficult to say if its always the same IP - im tracking that now, but IP addresses are randomly assigned in the subnet - overtime, we'll see them re-used.

Comment: When this happened today, with yet a different server, it suddenly cleared up after 7+ hours.  We made no changes and amazon claims they did not either.  The only thing we saw in the logs was a DHCP renewal, which happens around every 28 minutes and had occurred many times before without affect.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by ARP caching (MAC address caching) in new linux kernels.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1331150